# How to handle mouse up when the mouse leaves the div?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm creating an element that can be dragged, rotated, and scaled. It's basic structure looks like this:

```
<div class='interactable' @mousedown='handleDown' @mouseup='handleUp'>
</div>

<script>
  data: {
    dragging: false,
    resizing: false,
    rotating: false,
  },
  methods: {
    handleDown () {
      // code that sets dragging, resizing, rotating to true
    }
    handleUp () {
      this.dragging = false
      this.resizing = false
      this.rotating = false
    }
  }
</script>
```

It works okay. Only one problem: `mouseup` is not triggered if I release the mouse outside of the `div` (which make sense since the `mouseup` event is in the `interactable` div).

What's the common way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the `mouseUp` in the parent element by using a flag say `isDown`.

Set the `isDown` true on `mousedown` in the child.
Set the `isDown` false on `mouseup` in both child and the parent.

You can have multiple variables to detect multiple elements.

Hope code is self explanatory:

```js
var isDown = false;

function mouseup() {
  if (isDown) {
    alert("Mouse down has occured in child");
  }
  isDown = false;
}

function mousedown() {
  isDown = true;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" onmouseup="mouseup();">
  <div class="child" onmousedown="mousedown()" onmouseup="mouseup()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait I minute, I guess I can attach `handleUp` to the whole page?

Comment: Maybe! you just need to work on logic to suit your need and layout